# Modifying JQuery Code CSS Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery("#navmain li").click(function(){
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("selected");
        });

    });
</script>
```

It works fine BUT it's not working for class .first ... so when I select any other list item it's working but on the first list item I've assigned a class called .first I need so selected to work on that too.

I need to modify the above so that it also works with:

```
#navmain li.first
```

UPDATE:

This is the code I need to modify:

Home

I need to catch the SELECTED and add some style to it.

Comment: Are you sure this is the source of your problem? Your current code should work with the li.first as well.

Comment: what is your css for the selected class? I suspect that the styles which you have for `.first` are overriding the `.selected` so you will need to update the css.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using jQuery instead of $ inside the document ready but using $ outside?

Comment: I got this to work fine. Having extra classes on any of the li elements shouldn't make any difference, unless the 'first' style and the 'selected' style clash.

Comment: If the `first` class isn't really needed, you can consider removing it and using $("li:first") selector for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this live example.

It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nQdcR/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's must works. My example:
http://jsfiddle.net/f5JPy/2/